# How to use exceljs in angular 6

Tags: angular6, exceljs

When I tried to use `exceljs` in `Angular-6` like so

```
import * as excel from 'exceljs'

createExcel() {
  let workbook = new excel.Workbook()
}
```

even I just initialize a class and got this error. If I comment out this line `let workbook = new excel.Workbook()` then error gone

> ./node_modules/fs-constants/browser.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Developer\spire-client\node_modules\fs-constants'

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could import it as follow

```
import * as Excel from 'exceljs';
```

after that, you can use Exceljs:

```
const myWorkbook = new Excel.Workbook()
```

or

```
import * as Excel from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";
import * as ExcelProper from "exceljs";

let workbook: ExcelProper.Workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
```

As long as you just use the import from exceljs for type definitions and only use functions from the import from exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js, the app will run just fine and you still get type safety.

ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#create-a-workbook
https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/issues/348#issuecomment-320690232

Comment: as you proposed me this solution, at the same time I found it on [https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/issues/348#issuecomment-320690232). Thanks

Comment: Yes sir, most of the things like configurations and import you can get it from github issues page itself. Since I worked with Data Driven (Viz) websites. I used exceljs and glad you found the solution. and I added the ref too

Comment: If above doesn't work use this 

import * as ExcelJS from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";

let workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

Accessing it with name ExcelJS solved issue.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Import like this

`import * as Excel from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";`

and declare

`const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();`

It will work.

Comment: He has imported excel and excelproper in two lines and first one will not resolve the error alone.